# Gett css of screen coordintes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coordinates

i am kind trying to hack add a feature to a plugin.

My scenario is that a div is overlaid on top of a table with many cells. This div spans across many cells of the table under it. But it is not embedded in the table- as mentioned; but actually position set absolute x,y coordinates on the screen.

If i click that floating div i can get the jsEvent mouse coordinates x,y..

How can i then use those coordinates to get more data like the css of all elements at that coordinate eg the cells class,id,etc directly below the click x,y ? or all the cells directly below or above.

I am trying to use jQuery. Any suggestions.

Comment: The only cross-browser way to do that would be to loop through each td element, checking each offset with the mouse coords. Why can't you just use `$('td').click(function() {...});`?

Comment: because i am not clicking the actual table. i am clicking a div on top of the table that is NOT inside the table anywhere. So td click will never fire unless i click on the td and not the floating div.. see?

Comment: but the idea of going through all the td is not bad idea- but very inneficient.. any other suggestion?

Comment: The only other possible option would be `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`, but I think that gets the top element, so it probably wouldn't work (not to mention its not very compatible with different browsers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (where mousex and mousey are the coords):

```
$('td').each(function(index) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    if ((offset.left + $(this).outerWidth()) > mousex && offset.left < mousex && (offset.top + $(this).outerHeight()) > mousey && offset.top < mousey) {
       // $(this).css...
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$("#div").click(function(event){
  var x = event.pageX, y = event.pageY;
  var $clickedTd = $("#table td").filter(function(){
    var tdx = $(this).offset().left, tdy = $(this).offset().top;
    var tdw = $(this).width(), tdh = $(this).height();
    return (x >= tdx && x <= tdx+w && y >= tdy && y <= tdy + tdh);
  });
  //Here you have a reference to the clicked cell in $clickedTd. use it as you want;
});
```

What we're doing is to find the td that is just in the place we clicked (getting the div click coordinates).

Cheers

Comment: i looked at yours but grx seemed cleaner- and it worked copy and paste. Thanks for answer! Not sure about the efficiency though..